# Cocos 2dx game fails to run on mac os 64 bit but runs on ios simulator

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am able to run the cocos 2dx game on the ios simulator, but it gives an error when I try o run it for my desktop. I initially thought it was because of my touch functions, so I disabled them temporarily. It still didn't work. I use a Mac OS X El Capitan 64 bit. Can someone help me with this?  The following is the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "SplashScene::createScene()", referenced from:
      AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: too generic. please isolate the piece of code that generates the error, share it here with us, and let us know details about the error (code, message, stack trace

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible. But it's hard to help you, because you didn't provided any information about errors you have.

But, you for sure have to set Valid architectures (in desktop target) to i386 and x86_64 if you have something different here.